# USB-C cable working fine on one machine but on new 650B only USB 2.0

Tags: usb-c, amd-ryzen

I have a USB-C cable that works fine on my [ThinkPad T15 G Gen2](https://psref.lenovo.com/Product/ThinkPad/ThinkPad_T15g_Gen_2) and worked fine on my Z390 Intel MB.

But on my upgraded one (MSI 650B) it connects only with USB 2.0 (while other cable work). I use the cable to connect Meta Quest 3.

Is there a way to fix this? Why does this happen? And most important: Is there a way to know what cable are okay with my motherboard?

- This is the USB-C cable: [CABLETEX 5 m Link Cable for Meta Quest 3, Oculus Quest 2, PICO 4, PSVR2, Steam VR - USB 3.2 USB C Cable for VR Headset and Gaming PC, 5 Gbps Data Transfer](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B08N6HRX9P)
- I also have this one (still working), but it is USB-A: [ZYBER Link Cable 5 m for PICO 4/Oculus Quest 2, VR Headset Link Cable for Meta Quest Pro 2/1 Gaming PC, High Speed USB 3.0 to USB C Cable for PC (Black)](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B0BN1DMRB5)

What is special with original Meta Quest Link cable?

Answer (score 1):

There are 15 different configurations of USBC cables. There are 100s of different USB controllers, none of which I have ever seen implement the protocols they claim to support either correctly or completely.

I deal with many PCs, and many USB cables. Some cables will work in a certain slot. Then, later, the same cable will not work, in the same slot!

So, I look for universal 24-pin cables. I have four cables that work with pretty much everything.

It also depends on USBC to what? USBC<>USBC MALE you want 24-pin, here's an item number on eBay 223103427761

For USBA<>USBC future-proof cables work great. But there's also reversable cables vs OTG cables. OTG cables need a host on one side, and the hosted device on the other, usually an external USB storage drive, or anything without its own power. The OTG cable has a small resistor on one end to tell the host it's hosting what's on the other end.

But for cameras, phones, tablets, etc; reversable cables work. Of course, if the ends have different connectors, the cable can't be reversible.

24-pin cables are a sure bet, but you can't get them in every configuration. I hope this helps.

Comment: That eBay listing will fade away over time. I looked at the listing and nothing seems to indicate it’s a 24 pin cable. It also seems like a generic brand at best. Is there any better reference you can provide?